# xamandroidsupportv4-18-22.2.0.0 problems

Tags: xamarin

when add the xamandroidsupportv4-18-22.2.0.0 to xamarin project i got these errors

```
Error   4    cannot find symbol
symbol  : class OnActionExpandListener
location: class android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
    android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\MenuItemCompat_OnActionExpandListenerImplementor.java  8   41  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   5    cannot find symbol
symbol  : class OnApplyWindowInsetsListener
location: package android.support.v4.view
    android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\OnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor.java    8   26  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   10   cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ViewPropertyAnimatorListener
location: package android.support.v4.view
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\ViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor.java   8   26  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   11   cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListener
location: package android.support.v4.view
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\ViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.java 8   26  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   8    cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WindowInsetsCompat
location: package android.support.v4.view
private native android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat n_onApplyWindowInsets (android.view.View p0, android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat p1);
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\OnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor.java    32  128 HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   9    cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WindowInsetsCompat
location: package android.support.v4.view
private native android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat n_onApplyWindowInsets (android.view.View p0, android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat p1);
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\OnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor.java    32  40  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   6    cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WindowInsetsCompat
location: package android.support.v4.view
public android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets (android.view.View p0, android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat p1)
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\OnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor.java    27  118 HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   7    cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WindowInsetsCompat
location: package android.support.v4.view
public android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets (android.view.View p0, android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat p1)
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\OnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor.java    27  32  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   1    package android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat does not exist
    android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.OnActiveChangeListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\media\session\MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor.java 8   54  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   2    package android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider does not exist
    android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider.SubUiVisibilityListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\ActionProvider_SubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor.java 8   41  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   3    package android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider does not exist
    android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider.VisibilityListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\ActionProvider_VisibilityListenerImplementor.java  8   41  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   12   package android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout does not exist
    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\widget\DrawerLayout_DrawerListenerImplementor.java  8   41  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   13   package android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout does not exist
    android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\widget\SlidingPaneLayout_PanelSlideListenerImplementor.java 8   46  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
Error   14   package android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout does not exist
    android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
I:\HelloSwipeViewWithTabs\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\widget\SwipeRefreshLayout_OnRefreshListenerImplementor.java 8   47  HelloSwipeViewWithTabs
```